# Why C++ standard split container class into multiple header file?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, standards

I've been learning C++ for a while and getting confused about its container usage. If I want to use certain container I have to manually include them one by one. For example, if I want to use "vector" container I have to type `#include "vector"`, and if I need "list" container later I have to add `#include "list"`.

Why wouldn't C++ standard simply put every container class inside one header file, like `#include "container"`, so that developers could care less about including them one by one?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but standard headers should be included by `#include <vector>`, not `#include "vector"`. The latter works, but, in general, quotes are for non-standard headers.

Comment: If you want you can make a file named container which contains `include <...>` for all containers.

Comment: If I just want to use a vector, why would I want to include every other container type? There's quite a few of them.

Comment: MSVC's C++20 puts most in the module `std.core`, so `import std.core;` works there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why wouldn't C++ standard simply put every container class inside one header file, like `#include "container"`, so that developers could care less about including them one by one?

Performance, specifically compile time performance.  If you include everything, there is a lot of code that the compiler is going to have to deal with.  If you only use 1% of everything, then 99% of the code the compiler is working with is useless to you and just wasting your time having the compiler deal with it.

Comment: Then why they did that for "algorithm" and "iterator"?  These two header files simply wrapped everything about them.

Comment: @ArchBug Because there’s a lot more code involved in defining `vector` than there is in defining `sort`. The intent was to strike a balance between having too many headers and having too much needlessly included code.

Comment: @ArchBug While performance is a big concern, convenience also comes into play.  It would be overly onerous to have to include each function individually.  A lot of algorithms also depend on each other, so it makes sense to bucket them together.  With the containers, they don't depend on each other, and there are not that many, so it's better to leave them separated.  You'll see this with the Utility section of the standard as well.  There are a lot of sub-groups in it that are separated into their own header files as they don't depend on other sub-groups.